# Parametro URL Route PHP SLim v3

Tags: php, slim

estoy tratando de obtener via url(GET) un valor para poder usarlo luego:

la url seria asi http://misitio.com/blog/post donde post seria el parametro de URL

index.php

```
 require "core/model/config.php";
 require"core/model/routes.php";


 // Run app
 $app->run();
```

core/model/config.php

```
 <?php
 define("BASE_URL","http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ."/");

 require"vendor/autoload.php";

 $container['notFoundHandler'] = function ($c) {
 return function ($request, $response) use ($c) {
 return $c['view']->render($response->withStatus(404), '404.html');
 };
 };

 // Create app
 $app = new \Slim\App($container);

 // Get container
 $container = $app->getContainer();

 // Register PHP render component on container
 $container['PHPview'] = function ($container) {
 return new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer('core/view', [
    'cache' => false
 ]);
 };

 // Register component on container
 $container['view'] = function ($container) {
 $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('core/view', [
    'cache' => false
 ]);
 //Override the default Not Found Handler


 // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
 $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace('index.php', '',
 $container->get('request')->getUri()->getBasePath()), '/');
 $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views  
 \TwigExtension($container->get('router'), $basePath));
 $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal("current_path",   
 $container["request"]->getUri()->getPath());
 $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal("Domain", "http://"   
 .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] ."/");


 return $view;
 };

 require_once"core/model/functions.php";
```

core/model/functions.php

```
 $blog = new Twig_SimpleFunction('Blog', function ($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://blog.rbb-autoradio.com.ar    
 /' . $url . '/?json=1');
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $obj = json_decode($result);
 $cadena = $obj->post->content;
 $start  = strpos($cadena,"<!-- Start Sociable -->");
 $end  = strrpos($cadena,"<!-- End Sociable -->");
 $contenido = substr_replace($cadena,'',$start,$end);
 $html = "<h1>" . $obj->post->title . "</h1>";
 $html.= $contenido;

 return $html;
  });
 $container->get('view')->getEnvironment()->addFunction($blog);
```

core/model/routes.php

```
 <?php
 $app->get('/blog/{post}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
 return $this->view->render($response, 'post.html', ['post' =>    
 $args['post']]);
 });
```

post.html

```
 {% extends "main.layout.html" %}

 {% block head%}
 <link rel="amphtml" href="">
 {{ parent() }}
 {% endblock %}

 {% block title %}

 {% endblock %}

 {% block desc %}
 {% endblock %}

 {% block keysWords %}
 {% endblock %} 

 {% block sideNav%} 
 {% endblock %} 

 {% block container %}
 <!-- todo el contenido -->
 <div class="container">
 {% autoescape false %}
 {{ Blog(post) }}
 {% endautoescape %}
 </div>
 <!-- hasta aqui todo el contenido -->
 {% endblock %}
```

Editado: asi me funciona bien, lo que no puedo hacer es con una vista PHP

Comment: ¿[Revisaste la documentación](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#usage-with-slim-3)? Tu código parece algo diferente y no se ve que estés creando ciertas instancias.

Comment: Postea la plantilla html

Comment: la plantilla solo tiene un var_dump para ver si recibo algo en $_GET ya lo puse en mi respuesta editandola

Comment: A ver, ¿resolviste el problema, puesto que veo que escribiste una **respuesta**? Y, dices que aplicaste el ejemplo al pie de la letra, pero no estás usando `run` por ejemplo. Si no has resuelto el problema, borra la respuesta que pusiste abajo, colocándola en el área de la pregunta, diciendo, algo como *He intentado esto y tampoco funciona*. El área de abajo es sólo para respuestas. Stackoverflow no funciona como los foros, es importante tenerlo en cuenta. Gracias.

Comment: elimine la respuesta y puse todo en la pregunta